# insertion into unordered_map got lost

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, unordered-map

I'm having the following code, but after run the code, the result is empty, any ideas why the result is empty? the reference of result in function main was passed to myclass, I thought function addToResult will actually add data to result, and I'm expecting a map key = "test", value = "1": "1". I'm kind of new to c++. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using LookUpTable = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
using DLTable = std::unordered_map<std::string, LookUpTable>;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(DLTable& dltable) {
        m_dltable = dltable;
    };

    void addToResult() {
        LookUpTable ee;
        ee.emplace("1", "1");
        m_dltable.emplace("test", ee);
    };

 private:
    DLTable m_dltable;   
};


int main ()
{

  DLTable result;
  MyClass myclass(result);
  myclass.addToResult();

  std::cout << "myrecipe contains:" << std::endl;
  for (auto& x: result) {
        std::cout << x.first << ": "<< std::endl;
        for (auto& xx : x.second) {
            std::cout << xx.first << ": " << xx.second << std::endl;    
        }

  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the reference of result in function main was passed to myclass" -- great, and it gets copied into the class member `m_dltable` . "I thought function addToResult will actually add data to result" -- why? It adds it to the member of the class, called `m_dltable` which has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with the constructor's parameter, which gets copied into `m_dltable`. C++ does not work this way. Just because A was initialized from B doesn't mean that changes to A get automatically copied to B. Now, if `m_dltable` itself is a reference, then it would be a different story.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way around in the first place? Just write a getter function that returns a reference to `m_dltable` and use that to iterate over. Then you won't need to pass anything to the constructor either.

Comment: @Slava  A `const` reference. Otherwise you wouldn't make it `private` of course.

Comment: @walnut sorry for exaggerated reaction, but you need to be careful with your suggestions to novice programmer, OP already tried to get around incapsulation, his method was just too naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let' look into simplified example:

```
int a = 0;
int &b = a;
int c = b;

c = 123;
```

Will last assignment modify `a`? Of course not. It does not matter how you pass value to `c` through reference or not `c` is completely independent variable that just initialized by a reference.

Your case is the same - `m_dltable` is separate variable and the fact you initialize it using reference does not change anything. (Your case even worse, you did not initialize it by reference, you assigned to it)

In general your approach is wrong. If you want directly access that variable then just make it public, do not try to create convoluted workarounds on how to access it. If you want incapsulation just create members that allow you to iterate over that container. For example return a const reference to it or have `begin()` and `end()` methods that return (const) iterators accordingly.